# Markov Model Where Order Does Not Matter

Tags: probability

I am trying to figure out what this model would be called, and am not completely sure and hoping someone can help.

I have 5 predefined categories - A B C D E. I can have all categories or none, and want to evaluate the probability of each non-present catagory given the existing one. They may correlate, be mutually exclusive, or simply be uncorrelated.

FOR EXAMPLE

given: A B C are present (order does not matter)
return: P(D) or P(E) also being present based on a training set of co-occurrence.

BUT

I also want to know P(A) given none present, or the P(A) given C B are present. I also don't want the model assume that if in training E never occurs with A, that its not possible.

Appreciate any help here. I don't know what the name of this model would be.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the question. It sounds like you have $2^5$ states that can be organized nicely into a binary tree based on whether the state has property $A_j,j=1,\dots,5$. Then given a set of training data you want to estimate conditional probabilities, presumably with relatively few of the conditions invoked all at once. Is that right?

Comment: If that's right, being very naive I would just use counting and the usual conditional probability formula, leaving conditional probabilities conditioned on unobserved events undefined. But if you want to inject some of your own "bias" into the model (e.g. enforcing $P(A_5 \mid A_1)>0$ even though $A_5 \cap A_1$ was never observed), then you could use the usual Bayesian technique (postulate a prior, update the prior into a posterior using the data).

Comment: This bayesian prior may be the most accurate approach for this model. I have a large list of combinations of ABCD and E to train off of. I just cant believe there isnt some sort of prebuild model for this in R or python.

Comment: I'm sure there are machine learning libraries out there that work with this kind of thing, but which one you want to use will depend a bit on modeling aspects. Also, the exact thing that I just said is quite simple (probably under 100 lines of Python), so maybe it doesn't quite warrant a library by itself.

Comment: I think i agree.